# sql count only once per shop_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, math, count

```
$query = "SELECT shop_id, article_id, design_id FROM shop_tshirts WHERE design_id = '$design'";
$zres = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($zres);
```

I use this code to get the number of products that is using a specific $design.

Is it possible to count the products only ONCE per shop_id ?

Example with this DB structure:

```
shop_id / article_id / design_id
S01 / A01 / D01
S02 / A02 / D01
S03 / A03 / D01
S03 / A04 / D01
```

Usually with this structure, the result of my code would be 4... I want to change the code so the result would be 3, because D01 is being used twice in S03 and i want to count it only once per shop.

Thanks !

Comment: you can use distinct...select distinct shop_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct shop_id, article_id, design_id FROM shop_tshirts WHERE design_id = '$design'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use The SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT shop_id, article_id, design_id FROM shop_tshirts WHERE design_id = '$design'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need unique shop_id values

You don't need article_id or design_id

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT shop_id FROM shop_tshirts WHERE design_id ='$design'";
$zres = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($zres);
```